# Does being upwind/downwind affect my ability to sneak up on horses?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

While playing *Breath of the Wild*, I was trying to sneak up on a horse and noticed a few particles blowing the wind past me and towards the horse (I was upwind of the horse). I thought that the horses might be able to smell me because of that and shifted to the opposite direction, so that the wind would pass the horse before me (I was downwind of the horse).

I'm wondering though, is this something that the game actually takes into account? Does being upwind/downwind of a horse affect my ability to sneak up on them?

Comment: Horses in BOTW do not have a sense of smell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen no conclusive proof that wind direction does affect horse detection, nor does the guidebook make any mention of such a mechanic. It seems like all wind direction does is give you a boost to gliding if you're going in the same direction, and affect how fire spreads.

The only things that seem to affect when a Horse will detect you is noise level and line of sight.